# Compute the residue with the definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate $\underset{z=0}{\text{Res }} e^{\cot(z)}$ with the definition. So I need to integrate my function over tall rectangular with vertical sides intersecting real axis at $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$. But I can’t calculate it

Comment: This may be difficult. My copy of Mathematica cannot handle this, but it concedes that it can only calculate residues when it can find the Laurent series. The essential singulaty makes that taxing. Numerical integration does not suggest a simple rational value either. But, I'm not an expert on this.

Comment: There is no other way to do this . I mean easier